# One item (int) caching in JAVA with a special use case

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to cache an `int` value (counting something from a DB).
This count can potentially take a lot of time, I'd like to first try and do it with a timeout of 200 milliseconds.
But if it's failed I have 2 scenarios:

1. My `cache` is populated, return the current value and re-populate it asynchronously.
2. The `cache` is not populated, block by populating it and return the value.

I'm saying "cache" but it really is just an `int` value, I'm not sure a full blown `cache` is needed here.
I've tried using [Supplier](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html) from Guava, but I don't find a way to integrate my specific use case with it.

Bear in mind that many threads can enter this entire procedure, I only want the first one to wait in case the cache is not populated.
The rest should not wait and immediately get the cached value, an updated one if some other thread finished re-populating the cache.

Here is a sample code of what I have now:

```
public class CountRetriever {

private Supplier<Integer> cache = Suppliers.memoize(countSupplier());

private Supplier<Integer> countSupplier() {
    return new Supplier<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer get() {
            // Do heavy count from the DB
        }
    };
}

public int getCount() {
    try {
        return submitAsyncFetch();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // It takes too long, let's use the cache
        return cache.get();
    }
}

private Integer submitAsyncFetch() {
    return executor.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            // Do heavy count from the DB
        }
    }).get(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code? I was able to understand your problem, but it's hard to figure out a way to solve it without some code.

Comment: I've added my code sample

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
private int Map<String,Integer> cache = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

public getValue(String key){
  synchronized(cache){
    Integer value = cache.get(key);
    if(value == null) { 
       value = getValue();
       cache.put(key,value);
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Of course if a second thread comes in while the cache is being populated, it will have to wait. Also in this solution, only one Thread can read the value at once, so you might want replace the synchronized block with a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) although I doubt it will have a heavy effect on performance, given how simple the critical block is.

Comment: I think the op wants that if one thread is already updating the value, new threads should retrieve the old value istead of blocking

Comment: Ah I see... Well, then I'd suggest a different approach: have an independent thread that updates the value periodically, and return the value (updated or otherwise) to any asking thread (not just from the second on)

Comment: assylias is exactly right, though I'm now sure how to implement the "get old value only if it exists, otherwise block"